# When running detectron2: The checkpoint state_dict contains keys that are not used by the model: pixel_mean pixel_std

Tags: python, motion-detection, detectron

I implemented code that uses detectron2 to detect moving objects in short videos. Everything was working fine for a few weeks and then this warning appeared randomly out of nowhere, because I didn't change anything with the code nor did I install any updates.

Full warning after which the code does not proceed with detection:

```
D:\detectron2>python motion_detection_2.py
[02/27 12:39:29 d2.checkpoint.detection_checkpoint]: [DetectionCheckpointer] Loading from detectron2://PointRend/InstanceSegmentation/pointrend_rcnn_X_101_32x8d_FPN_3x_coco/28119989/model_final_ba17b9.pkl ...
WARNING [02/27 12:39:30 d2.projects.point_rend.mask_head]: Weight format of PointRend models have changed! Applying automatic conversion now ...
The checkpoint state_dict contains keys that are not used by the model:
  pixel_mean
  pixel_std
```

Did anyone encounter similar problem and have any idea how to fix it?

I tried checking detectron2 files to look for the missing keys. I found this instead:

detectron2/checkpoint/detection_checkpoint.py
line 129

```
for k in ["pixel_mean", "pixel_std"]:
            # Ignore missing key message about pixel_mean/std.
            # Though they may be missing in old checkpoints, they will be correctly
            # initialized from config anyway.
            if k in model_buffers:
                try:
                    incompatible.missing_keys.remove(k)
                except ValueError:
                    pass
```

I checked if this code is being used when running my script and it indeed is. So now I am even more confused.